# ASP.NET Temporary folder content

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, iis-7.5, temp

I have a web app hosted in IIS 7.5 with ASP.NET 4.0.
Today I updated an existing usercontrol. And when I tried to view the corresponding page the below mentioned error appeared.

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'UserControls_QuickFinders_PrinterSuppliers_New' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\721411d6\d7119521\App_Web_sqsfz2yg.dll' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\721411d6\d7119521\App_Web_printersuppliers_new.ascx.a11d5f6c.czdzfssn.dll'``
```

My Usercontrol's name is : `PrinterSuppliers_New`

I tried by restarting the site and restarting applications pool. Also found the above mentioned dlls inside the

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\721411d6\d7119521\ path of the server.
```

I am not sure of deleting them since there are other web apps which are hosted in the same server. Kindly advise me in this. Will an application pool recycle on demand help? If so are there any consequences?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The files and folders you see within the `Temporary ASP.NET Files` are normal, they are the result of the ASP.NET compilation process which occurs on web application startup.

You can remove unused files and folders using the following PowerShell command, it may be worth recycling your websites application pool before doing so (to ensure your websites files are not locked):

`Get-ChildItem "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework*\v*\Temporary ASP.NET Files" -Recurse | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force`

Comment: The issue was fixed after recycling the Application pool and then removing the files.